# Is there a way to capture cancelled requests using a har proxy?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver, har

in my project, I have some JavaScript responsible for tracking user actions in order to optimize the page's layout. These calls are executed when the user clicks something, including the links leading to further pages.

I have the whole flow covered by automated tests written in Java and based on Selenium Webdriver. I'm using a Browsermob proxy to capture the requests and verify that the correct data is being passed to the user tracking service.

In certain situations, the requests hitting the service do not get recorded by the proxy. The reason this happens is because the browser navigates to the next page before getting the response from the tracking service. The request actually hits the destination, which I can see by the state of the database. Because the browser does not wait for the responses, they happen not to be noticed by the proxy, despite the [default 5 second wait](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.lightbody.bmp/browsermob-proxy/2.0-beta-8/net/lightbody/bmp/proxy/ProxyServer.java), which just seems to be ignored in this case. This only happens once in a while, causing false negatives in my test reports.

I can't force the browser to actually wait for those requests because I don't want the tracking to impede the user journey. What I'd like to do is to somehow configure the proxy to tell the difference between requests that have not been sent and the ones cancelled midway. This way I could attach this information to my reports.

Is this possible to achieve using the Browsermob proxy? Perhaps some other tool would do a better job.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use phantomjs webDriver implementation, we don't need to initiate jetty proxy server and we can get all requests even those without responses.